# How to add an additional parameter to the id attribute in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a loop where I get all input fields. All of these inputs have a id. What I want to achieve is that I only add an additional string to the existing id. I guess it is easy but I can not find anything.

I tried this, but it only replaces the existing ID with the new ID:

```
$('input').attr('id', '_' + votingID);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this you can pass a function to the `attr()` method. This function accepts two arguments; the index of the current element, and its current setting. All you need to do is return the new value from that function based on the current one, like this:

```
$('input').attr('id', function(i, id) {
  return id + '_' + votingID;
});
```

More info in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could pass a function as the second parameter in order to iterate through elements.

Comment: It's a very handy pattern which jQuery uses in quite a few places. Keep an eye out for it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.attr()` function with 2 parameters replaces the value for the attribute equal to the first parameter with the second parameter. If you call `$.attr()` with one argument (e.g. `$.attr('id')`) you get the value of the attribute specified.

With this information you can do what you want:

```
$('input').attr('id', $('input').attr('id') + '_'+votingID);
```

If you have more than 1 input though, this will probably not work correctly, and you will have to use `$.each()` like so:

```
$('input').each(function(index, value) {
    $(value).attr('id', $(value).attr('id') + '_'+votingID);
});
```